# Finding derivative with integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

[image]

Came to this problem on my test study guide. I thought for finding the derivative you just took the antiderivative, which would be -cos(theta). How is it sin(x)? Or did I come across another error? At this point In this class I never know anymore.

Comment: It's one of those Fundamental Theorems of calculus (1 or 2 I don't know). The derivative of the integral is "the function itself" subject to upper and lower value. but the sine of pi is zero

Comment: I have both of those copied down word for word from the lecture and both are using the antiderivative... huh.

Comment: Out of the two fundamental theorems of calculus, the one you need is probably the least "intuitive". Answers below may give a clue. I couldn't word it much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the second fundamental theorem of calculus, which states that if a function $F$ is continuous on open interval $I$ and $a \in I$ with $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt $ then $F'(x)=f(x)$

You can verify it by first evaluating $\int_\pi^x \sin \theta \, d\theta $, then taking the derivative with respect to $x$. i.e. $$\int_{\pi }^x  \sin \theta \, d\theta = - \cos x -(-  \cos \pi)= -\cos x-1 \\
\Rightarrow g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (-\cos x -1 ) = \sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $[\pi, a] \subset \Bbb{R}$; let $f: x \mapsto \sin x: [\pi,a] \to \Bbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[\pi,a]$ and hence, by fundamental theorem of calculus, the map $f$ is the derivative of the map $g: x \mapsto \int_{\pi}^{x}\sin \theta d\theta: ]\pi,a[ \to \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=\int_\pi^x\sin\theta\,d\theta=-\cos x+\cos\pi=-\cos (x)-1$$then
$$g'(x)=[-\cos (x)-1]'=\sin x$$